# Environment.OSVersion sometimes reporting Windows 8 for 8.1, although manifest is set correctly

Tags: c#, windows, .net-4.5

Since `Environment.OSVersion` may [lie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17399302/how-can-i-detect-windows-8-1-in-a-desktop-application) about whether Win 8 or 8.1 is running, we declared in our [manifest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn481241%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) specifically that we target Windows 8.1 in our application.

However, `Environment.OSVersion.Minor` seems to be unreliable in returning the version. We wrapped it in one of our libraries, but on some of our dev machines, it returns "2" (Windows 8), on other "3" (Windows 8.1). There aren't any specific compatibility settings applied (as far as we know), but we can't seem to track the issue down.

Are there other options to get the Windows version via .Net, without using the Win32 API functions mentioned at MSDN?

Comment: `Environment.OSVersion` uses the same underlying Win32 functions, so I don't think those will help. I think you need to get to the bottom of why it lies sometimes, because that lie is implemented everywhere. An unsupported but "will probably work today but might not on the next version of Windows" approach is to peek at the `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion` registry value.

Comment: Try using WMI, in the Win32_OperatingSystem class.

Comment: @mike z Thanks, I did it that way. If you want to post it as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: @Lennart yea I didn't really think I was going to get around to an answer, so +1 on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Allright, I did it with WMI as @mike-z suggested:

```
SelectQuery query = new SelectQuery(@"Select * from Win32_OperatingSystem");
string wmiVersion = String.Empty;

using (ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(query))
{                    
  foreach (var process in searcher.Get())
  {
     wmiVersion = process["Version"].ToString().Substring(0, 3);
  }
}  

switch (wmiVersion)
{
 case "6.3": return "Windows 8.1";
 // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

*Disclaimer: this is meant as a "when everything else fails..." kind of answer*

You could parse the output of `VER` and see if it's accurate.

On my box (8.1 Pro) I see this

> C:> ver
>
> Microsoft Windows [Version 6.3.9600]
>
> C:>